# Exibir mensagem ao invés de erro?

Tags: php

Tenho uma função de consulta em BD que necessita da função `conectar` que está em outro arquivo, no arquivo dela não dei `include`, preferi colocar o `include` antes de chamar a função `consultar`, pois pode haver casos que o caminho mude.

Estou tendo um problema ao exibir uma mensagem personalizada quando ele não acha a função:

```
@$conexao = conectar();
    if($conexao == false or $conexao == NULL)
    {   //falta include de conexao.php
        echo "Não há uma conexão ativa com o seu banco de dados!\n<br><i>Inclua a página ../conexao.php<br>";
        return false;
    }
```

Função conectar:

```
function conectar()
{
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbname = "teste";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    try
    {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$dbhost};dbname={$dbname}", $dbuser, $dbpass);
        $conn ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return true;
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex)
    {
        echo "Erro de conexão: " . $ex->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Como falei, as funçãos `conectar` e `consultar` estão em arquivos distintos e não coloquei o `include 'conexao.php'` no arquivo da outra função para não dar erro de caminho, a dúvida é como exibir o `echo` quando minha função `conectar` não estiver definida, ou seja, quando não for encontrada.

Comment: O que acontece? ou o que não acontece? precisa mesmo daquela arroba?

Comment: Ele não entra no `if` quando eu retiro o include da função conectar

Comment: Está usando o PDO? por acaso tem um `try-catch` dentro da função?

Comment: Sim, sim, completei o post com a função e mais descrição do problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para saber se alguma função existe ou já foi definida use [function_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php)

```
if(function_exists('conectar')){
  $conexao = conectar();
}else{
  echo 'função não foi definida';
}
```

Comment: Acabei de achar na documentação do php rsrs Obrigado pela atenção!